# Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

Tags: ios, code-signing

I am an iOS developer and recently i ran in to one weird issue with apple signing certificates, My problem is i have an app build with a production certificate and it works very well but when i use same certificate to build another app it throws me an error mentioned below:
**"The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)."**
I am not sure what is wrong?

Comment: your provisional profile might be created with old certificates which are revoked or not selected while creating  provisional profile

Comment: No, i verified both certificate and provisioning profile is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself and found that the test project was set to the same profile as the app project and this caused the issue.  For detail take a look at the answer here:

[Entitlements don't match Provisioning Profile (0xE8008016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985359/entitlements-dont-match-provisioning-profile-0xe8008016/44738857#44738857)

You can also solve this during build by deselecting the test project in the scheme-build configuration.

After hours wasted this ended up being the solution for me.  Hope this helps.