# Entitlements don't match Provisioning Profile (0xE8008016)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, code-signing

today I finally got my Company-Developer-Account. I'm working on an App, first on my private Account and today I wanted to move the App to the company account. So I created a new Bundle-Identifier on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and changed the Bundle-Identifier also in my Xcode-Project. Furthermore, I've added the Account to Xcode, changed Signing to my new Company Account and let Xcode fix the Provisioning-File-Troubles. (In Xcode I see two Team-Members from one Account, one is Agent, the other User. Maybe it's important that I've choose the Agent-Team-Member. Unfortunately I can't change because then I get the error "change to a unique bundle-id, because the bundle-id is already on the Agent-Team?^^) Running with the Simulator works fine, but when I want to test on my Phone I get the following Error:  `The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).`

If I press the I next to the provisioning file, I see the following Entitlements:
[image]

And under Entitlements I've just the Push-Notifications enabled. But this was like this before changing Bundle Identifier

Comment: I recommend not to use `Xcode`'s auto fix feature. Do it manually. Check your provisioning profile is matching with the capability you set in your project such as `iCloud` and `Push Notifications`.

Comment: Hmmm ok I've changed but I can only select the XC iOS: ... Profile for Debug and Release, not the iOS Team Provisioning Profile which is the Debug-Profile I think. Still the same error

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had this same problem and none of the solutions I found on stack overflow, or github worked for me.

Here's my solution:

1. Select your project in the Project navigator [image]
2. Select the "General" tab.
3. To the left of the "General" tab, select your target to the left; (this should show a dropdown with a list of targets)
4. Below your current target you should see an item {your project}Tests; select that.
5. Check the signing properties in the general tab and make sure they are valid.

This was the problem for me.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I was stuck on this for 2 hours. Tests had a different Team selected then the normal one. And xcode is supposedly managing them automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 9 GM.
Error appears if manual signing turned on.

Turn on automatic code signing.
Turn off automatic code signing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through all the details where your provisional profile and certificate getting set from the main page.

E.g. In all **targets - > Build settings -> Code signing identity and provisinign profile and set your correct profiles every where in the application.**

sometimes when you are selecting manual codesigning then it is not reflecting correcly in all places.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your application from your device and then run your app on Xcode  , i think that current app that was on your device signed with old account so you cannot  run your new app that was assigned with new account , hope to help .

Comment: I did already.. I also tried to install via TestFlight (worked) and then from Xcode.. Unfortunately it didn't work... Still the Same..

Comment: you try install from Xcode and app from TestFlight  already installed on device  ?

Comment: try to turn off and turn on to all your capapitilies

Answer (score 0):

For me, I ended up getting this error when I did not have the private key associated with the certificate that was being used to sign the app. Make sure you open Keychain Access and verify that you have a private key for the certificate that is associated with your provisioning profile.